# C++ параметры по-умолчанию для конструктора базового класса

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор

Есть есть класс `А`, от него наследуется `В` и я хочу поставить для консруктора `А` параметры по-умолчанию, то придется пробрасывать их через коснруктор `В`(или же продублировать установки по-умолчанию в конструкторе `В`)? Т.е. как-то так:

```
A::A(T1 a=10, T2 b=10, T3 c=11)
{
...
}
B::B(T1 a, T2 b=10, T3 c=11):A(a,b,c)
{
...
}
```

По-другому никак не избежать пробрасывания?

Comment: Просто `B::B(T1 a, T2 b=10, T3 c=11):A()`. Можно даже не указывать `A()`... Вы же хотите, чтобы `A` был с параметрами по умолчанию **при любых** параметрах `B`? Или нет? Поясните точнее.

Comment: @Harry мне нужно, чтобы при создании `B` базовый класс `A` всегда получал некоторые параметры, но ничего кроме пробрасывания через конструктор `В` как-то не приходит в голову

Comment: "Некоторые" — это какие именно? Всегда одни и те же? Те, которые вы передаете в `B`? Какие?

Comment: @Harry да,те которые передаю в `B`

Comment: Тогда их надо указать в `A`, как вы и сделали. Тогда ваш вопрос совершенно непонятен — как вы хотите избежать передачи необходимых параметров ("без пробрасывания")? Представим на секунду, что вы можете просто указать, как бы вы хотели, а С++ с этим справится :) Так какой код вы *хотели бы* видеть? Как, по-вашему, должна выглядеть желаемая вами функциональность?

Comment: @Harry ну что-то вроде `...=new B(a):A(b,c)` ))

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите передавать в `B` значения по умолчанию, но при этом в `A` — не их, а какие-то иные значения? Так? Я просто никак не могу понять, чем вам не нравится написанный вами же в вопросе код... И чем не нравится `...=new B(a,b,c)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class  B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A; // наследуем все констркторы, каке есть в A
private:
    int x=42; // Если в B есть члены, которые требуется инициализировать 
              // специальным знечением, можно использовать указание значения 
              // по умолканию, в точке декларации члена.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Моя попытка решить через пробрасывание (perfect forwarding).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class A {
public:
    T1 a;
    T2 b;
    T3 c;

    A(T1 a = 10, T2 b = 10, T3 c = 11): a{a}, b{b}, c{c} {}
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class B: public A<T1, T2, T3> {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    B(T1 a, Args&&... args): A<T1, T2, T3>(a, std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

int main() {
    B<int, int, int> b(1, 2);
    std::cout << b.a << " " << b.b << " " << b.c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
1 2 11
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [std::forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)
- [Parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)
- [Rvalues лекция](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_u5fNg1lwQ)
- [Variadic templates (perfect forwarding) лекция](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5SUIRMzTgw)

Comment: ОП вроде как спрашивал про пробрасывание значений аргументов конструктора по-умолчанию.

Comment: @user7860670 В примере это и происходит. Аргумент `c` не задан, поэтому его значение по умолчанию равно 11. Изменил код, чтобы было понятнее.